# Capybara: How to select drop down value from below html

Tags: capybara

Capybara: How to select drop down value from below html

Month
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12

Comment: <select data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1" selected="">
<option class="option" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1.$0" value="0">Month</option>
<option class="option" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1.$1" value="1">01</option>
<option class="option" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1.$2" value="2">02</option>
<option class="option" data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1.$3" value="3">03</option>
</select>

Comment: I have tried with page.select("01", :from => "data-reactid") but no luck

Comment: within '#.0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1' do  find("option[value='08']").clickend

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Along with editing your question, add the exact error message you get

Answer (score 2):

The `from` option to `select` takes either the id, name, placeholder, or the text of an associated label element of the select element.  "data-reactid" is none of those.  Given the html you have put in the comments (please edit your question and add it there) you could just do

```
select("01")  # assumes there are no other select boxes with that option on the page
```

or you could do

```
find('select[data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1"]').select("01")
```

which is just short for

```
find('select[data-reactid=".0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1"]').find(:option, "01").select_option
```

Note: `within '#.0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1'` isn't going to do anything since within takes a css selector and none of your elements have the id  '#.0.0.1.1.2.1.$0.0.2.0.1'  ( a data-reactid is not an id ) .  On top of that the selector as written is invalid and would probably need to be `within '#\.0\.0\.1\.1\.2\.1\.\$0\.0\.2\.0\.1'` if an element with that id existed